# Watch multiple css files with postcss and output a bundle.css

Tags: node.js, build, npm, watch, postcss

I'm trying to figure out a workflow involving postcss. My need is to have css partials in one folder, watch them and output a bundle css file. The bundle css file must have include a base.css file at the top.

postcss has a --watch flag and can watch multiple files but can only output multiple files and not a bundle css file. I can use `cat` to combine all the files and use stdin to pipe them to postcss. But I can't trigger the `cat` command from postcss.

My files structure could look like this:

```
partials/
    |_one.css
    |_two.css
styles/
    |_base.css
    |_bundle.css
```

How would I, by using npm, arrange my script section to use CLI commands to achieve my goal?

My main issue is to figure out how to orchestra the build steps without one step blocking the next. A link to a working work-flow example would be great!

**EDIT** I got a solution working but it is very suboptimal as it can not be used with sourcemaps, can not have global variables and is a two step process. But I will outline it here in hope that someone can suggest a better approach.

Using the following structure:

```
build/
    |_stylesheet/
        |_default.css (final processed css)
partials/
    |_one.css
    |_one.htm (html snippet example)
    |_two.css
    |_two.htm (html snippet example)
styles/
    |_base.css
    |_bundle/ (css files from partial/ that is partly processed)
        |_one.css
        |_two.css
    |_master.css (import rules)
```

I have a two step process in my `package.json`. First I make sure I have a styles/bundle folder (`mkdir -p`) and then I start [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to watch the css files in partials/. When a change occurs, nodemon runs `npm run css:build`.

`css:build` process the css files in partials/ and output them in styles/bundle/ (remember that I don't know how to watch multiple files and output one bundled file).

After running `css:build`, npm runs `postcss:build` which processes the master.css file that @import css files from styles/bundle/. I then output (>) the processed content from stdout to build/stylesheet/default.css.

```
{
    "css": "mkdir -p styles/bundle && nodemon -I --ext css --watch partials/ --exec 'npm run css:build'",
    "css:build": "postcss --use lost --use postcss-cssnext --dir styles/bundle/ partials/*.css",
    "postcss:build": "postcss --use postcss-import --use postcss-cssnext --use cssnano styles/master.css > build/stylesheet/default.css",
}
```

Comment: You could check out [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with the [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) module. There is also a [gulp-postcss](https://github.com/postcss/gulp-postcss) module although I haven't used that one myself.

Comment: I want to avoid using Gulp or Grunt. I have worked with both and are convinced that I can achieve a more future proof work flow by using **npm** and OS tools. But I'm pretty new to this approach and don't know the *best practice* for listening and triggering commands.

Comment: how about using something like this?: `"css:build": "cat partials/*.css | postcss -u lost -u postcss-cssnext | cat styles/_base.css -  > default.css" `. Will do it in one step. But you won't get sourcemaps, since `postcss-cli` has no option for source maps.

Comment: you can trigger npm command after postcss `"css:build": "postcss --use lost --use postcss-cssnext --dir styles/bundle/ partials/*.css && npm run concat"`,

Answer (score 4):

You can check out `watch` and `parallelshell` packages from npm. I believe the combo of those two will do the trick. More on that here: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

Comment: Worked well with the package `watch`, given a script called `"css:build"` that does the actual work: `"watch": "watch 'npm run css:build' css"`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should consider using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html) instead to build a single css file and other resources which also has a watch flag. It is very efficient and you don't need to manually rebuild all the time after changes to resources/files.